# How to create iOS app with multiple sdk versions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My app is basically built in iOS sdk 4, and it is nearly completed.

I am looking to use one or two new features in sdk 5, should I need to create or re-factor the current app in sdk 5 ?

Could I submit an app with multiple sdk versions to Apple ? (e.g. one is built & deployed in sdk4, and the other is built & deployed in sdk5) ?

Any smart ways to tackle the above problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You us the 5.0 SDK and set the deployment target to 4.x. You will need to check if classes and selectors are available using `NSClassFromString` and `-respondsToSelector:`.

Have a look at '[Session 130 - Future Proofing your Application](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=130)' from WWDC 2010.

Comment: I could not find the video. Would you please provide a URL ?

Comment: I've added a link in my answer.